# width of element change between two values

Tags: css

Is there any way to force an element to have one of our desire width values?

for instance :
the min-width is 100px  but if the element needs more space the next step was 200px, not the content it takes.

the purpose is switching between specific widths.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can approximate this using `clamp()` like below:

Resize the wrapper to see the switch

```css
.box {
  width: clamp(100px, (100% - 200px)*1000, 200px);
  background: red;
  height: 100px;
}

.wrapper {
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 2px solid;
  resize: horizontal;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box"></div>

</div>
```

The logic is simple. If `100%` is bigger than `200px`, the difference mutiplied with `1000` will get bigger than `200px` so the width is `200px`. If 100% is maller than `200px`, the difference is negative so smaller than `100px` and we end with `100px`.